# API repsonse for me/tracks appears shows playback_count as 0

Tags: soundcloud

Currently our responses for the me/tracks endpoint on api.soundcloud.com are returning all 0's for playback_count for each track.

But when using to API to look at a specific track it does show plays. (eg.https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/[id]?secret_token=[token])

All other fields in the response for me/tracks have data, such as download_count.

This was working in the past, but unsure when it stopped.

Is there something we are missing to re-enable this data for this endpoint? Or is there any known issue with the API around this?

Comment: Update: We have tested the same endpoint using the users id (eg "users/[id]/tracks") rather than "me" and it does return the playback_count. Therefore I believe this is a bug in the "me" endpoint.

Comment: Same thing here with /me/activities/tracks/affiliated